# Erro 500 ao trazer muitos registros

Tags: php

Estou tentando exibir dados em uma `table` através de um `foreach` no `php` de mais de 17 mil registros do banco de dados, mas mostra `HTTP ERROR 500` no navegador.

```
 <?php foreach($dados as $dado):?>
   <tr>
      ... // aqui vai os registros
   </tr>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

O interessante é que quando eu limito a quantidade de registros para exibir, por exemplo 5 mil, o erro não ocorre.

Seria isso um problema de memória do `php`?

Tal vez eu não deva usar o `foreach`?

Edit:

Log do apache:

```
[Fri Sep 21 10:06:00 2018] [error] [client 192.168.0.100] PHP Fatal error:  
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 27316224 
bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: 
http://192.168.0.100/index.php/relatorio/
```

Comment: Precisa olhar o log de erro do apache.

Comment: obrigado pela dica.. realmente estorou o limite de memória. Eu devo aumentar ou tratar isso no php?

Comment: Quanto ao negativo parece um pouco exagerado, use o link [edit] e adiciona a mensagem de erro do log. Da forma como está não é possível saber em qual ponto está o problema.

Comment: O ideal seria não trazer todos os registros.

Comment: Editei com o log. Tal vez quebrando em partes o sql e trazendo aos poucos

Comment: A solução será paginar os dados mesmo, não tem muito o que fazer. A questão é: você precisa mesmo de 17 mil registros na mesma página? Isso parece ser desnecessário. Até 5 mil parece ser demais.

Comment: Sim, é um relatório e se eu usar paginação, o plugin do excel não funciona. Existe algum jeito de limpar a memória em cada iteração do loop?

Comment: Uma: você não precisa criar um *array* com todos os registros do banco. aparentemente você tem em `$dados` todos os registros, mas geralmente o driver do banco implementa um esquema de ponteiro entre os registros, possibilitando ter em memória apenas um registro por vez. Dois: se o PHP está gerando um código HTML a partir dos registros, com 17 mil registros o HTML ficará gigantesco, porém você pode facilitar a vida do seu servidor liberando o buffer de saída a cada iteração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo porque o seu script está consumindo mais recursos do que o php está configurado para permitir. Você poderia aumentar o limite, mas não recomendo por ser o equivalente a jogar a poeira para debaixo do tapete.

O ideal seria você inspecionar o seu código para descobrir onde está o vazamento de memória. Já passei por um problema parecido e refatorando o código  consegui reduzir a utilização de memória de 3GB para 300MB. Uma das mudanças que fiz foi trocar o foreach por um for da seguinte forma:

```
for ($i=0, $n = count($dados); $i < $n; $i++){
    $dado = $dados[$i]; //Instancia uma variável para trabalhar nesse escopo

    ... //Sua lógica aqui, usando $dado;

    unset($dados[$i]); //Libera memória a cada interação

}
```

Você pode medir o consumo de memória acrescentando `memory_get_usage()` no começo ou final de cada interação do loop.

```
echo ((memory_get_usage(true)/1024)/1024) . 'MB';
```

OBS: Li hoje que a utilização de um loop `foreach ($foo as &$bar)` é mais leve quando utilizando arrays de dados pesados. Mas use com cautela pois essa mesma sintaxe tende a ser a mais lenta quando usando poucos dados.

Comment: Se vc medir o tempo de execução vai ver aquele `count()` pesa mais. Dificilmente vc vai ter algum problema de leak em um script ou linguagem de script.

Comment: rray, você chegou a fazer algum benchmark que possa ter verificado isso? Com o meu volume de dados, essa foi a implementação mais leve em termos de utilização de memória (apesar de em muitas outras situações, o foreach comum ser a mais leve). De fato, a velocidade de execução não foi sequer levada em consideração por mim, já que o autor não apresentou problemas de timeout ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Pode ver o resultado com esses links https://3v4l.org/Xm0Jo#output, https://3v4l.org/Z6RVX, https://3v4l.org/efW7a. Pode testar na sua máquina com outras opções veja => https://ideone.com/FpmiA5

Comment: Grato pelos links e pelo site para teste (eu não conhecia hehe). Mas como eu disse, existem situações que uma implementação pode vir a ficar mais rápida que outra - e vice-versa. No meu caso, o count() teve desempenho melhor do que o foreach, no que diz respeito ao consumo de memória. Por isso o ideal é sempre testar todas as alternativas e ver qual se adequa melhor ao seu cenário. Conhecimento é munição. Paz.